# How to Get the Closing </html> in HTML DOM Parser with PHP

Tags: php, html

i'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and the difficulty of how to find the `</html>` tag. Because I want to add something right before the `</html>` tag.

```
</body>  
// add there
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to add something outside the body, out of interest?

Comment: Why don't you use the str_replace('</html>', 'INSERT</html>', $html); ???

Comment: Putting something there would make your html invalid if it's anything but a comment.